# Boolean function using switch statement in swift

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I'm trying to get a boolean result using a switch statement but I guess that there is something wrong in my code

```
class func login(username: String , password: String) -> Bool {
    let url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/login/"+username+"/"+password
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .failure:
            // print(error)
            return false
        case .success:
            // print(value)
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use completion handler with `Bool` parameter instead of returning value

```
class func login(username : String , password : String, _ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ())
```

now you can call completion like this (also fix cases with declaring `error` and `value`)

```
switch response.result {
case .failure(let error):
    //print(error)
    completion(false)
case .success(let value):
    //print (value)
    completion(true)
}
```

then you have access to `Bool` parameter inside its closure when completion is called.

```
Foo.login(username: "", password: "") { success in 
    // print(success)
    ...
}
```

Comment: this is my first time using completion handler so I didn't understand how to use it 
I want to call my function login so if the result is true I can pass to the next view controller

Comment: @LouayBaccary in closure instead of my dots pass something like `if success { and here you can present next ViewController }`

Comment: I tried this code but it didn't work 
  API.login(username: textUsername.text!, password: textPassword.text!) {
            success in
            print("Welcome")
        }

Comment: @LouayBaccary and are you calling `completion(true)` and `completion(false)` in switch?

Comment: this is the code
       switch response.result
            {
    case .failure:
    //print(error)
    completion(false)
    case .success:
    //print (value)
    completion(true)
                
            }

Comment: @LouayBaccary have a look to updated `switch` in my answer

Comment: I updated my question take a look , I tried your solution but it didn't work

Comment: @LouayBaccary never edit question depending on answer

Comment: @LouayBaccary Btw don’t declare failure in closure, just work with success as I wrote in my answer, if success is true, it means that result is success, if success in closure is false, result is failure. So: `API.login(username: textUsername.text!, password: textPassword.text!) { success in if success { print("Welcome")} else { print("NO")} }`

Comment: I tried it but it always print ("welcome")

Comment: @LouayBaccary then there result is always success, no errors... that is good isnt it?

Comment: no the main goal is if i type the correct username and password it print hello else it prints no

Comment: @LouayBaccary it looks like request works so problem is probably with your backend

Answer (score 0):

```
typealias CompletionClosure = (Bool) -> Void
class func login(username : String , password : String, completionHandler: @escaping CompletionClosure)   {
        let url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/login/"+username+"/"+password
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON{response in
        switch response.result
              {
        case .failure:
            //print(error)
            completionHandler(false)
        case .success:
            //print (value)
            completionHandler(true)
            }
    }
```

usage

```
login(username: "username", password: "password", completionHandler: { result in
print("Your result is \(result)")
})
```

You have to use a completion handler because this code works in an asynchronous way. Simply put, you 'charge the code' to execute later. And completion is fired when the work is done. You can revert such code into usual way but you have to use mutex and be careful about thread blocking operations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a completion handler:

```
class func login(username: String, password: String, completion: (Bool) -> Void) {
    let url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/login/" + username + "/" + password
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .failure:
            completion(false)
            // print(error)
        case .success:
            // print(value)
            completion(true)
        }
    }
}
```